# jquery grabbing current div or wildcard placeholder for show/hide function

Tags: php, jquery

i have the code below

```
<div id=topbar>
<a class="nav" href="#" onClick="if($('#embedding').css('display') == 'none') { $('#embedding').show('fast'); } else { $('#embedding').hide('fast'); } return false;">Show Details</a>
<div id=embedding>Content</div>
</div>
```

In the link to show the embedding layer, is there any way instead of putting #embedding, i can do something so it grabs the next div so i can use this dynamically?

Wanting to use this to format some MySQL results in PHP.

**UPDATE**
for those who are wondering, this is the solution

```
<a class="nav" href="#" onClick="if($(this).next('div').css('display') == 'none') { $(this).next('div').show('fast'); } else { $(this).next('div').hide('fast'); } return false;">Show Details</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [next()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next) method of jquery object:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).next('div').toggle();">Toggle next div</a>
```